# Java android put a variable to find a spinner id

Tags: java, android

I have a xml layout where is my spinner with id "test"
How can I put my variable "IdSpinner" into R object.
I want to make a common method to create  a lot of spinners ,where argument is a spinner id.

```
listLanguage('test');

public void listLanguage(String test) {
   final Spinner spinnerLanguage = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id....);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in this way (if I understood correctly)- I mean put idSpinner in R.id..., use another approach - just create dynamically `Spinner` object, in this case you can create as much Spinners as you want.